# input number in structs - check it already exists in file

Tags: c, struct, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to write a data validation function, where the ID number has to be a unique number in an array of structs. Every time I try to save a valid ID number, the program is crashing - why is this happening?

this is the struct, and the declaration of an array of structs:

```
struct customer {                   // set up customer template    //
    char name [MAXNAM];
    char surname [MAXNAM];
    int idnum [MAX_ID];
    };
struct customer data_cus[MAXCUS];
```

this is within the main program:

```
printf ("Please Enter ID Card, [NOTE! Only numbers are allowed!]\n");
                int checkID;

                while ((scanf ("%d",&checkID) == 0 || customerID(checkID, count)==1))
                {
                    printf ("This ID is already taken! Please enter unique ID!\n");
                    while (getchar()!='\n')
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    *data_cus[count].idnum = checkID;
                }
```

Here is the function used to check id the ID already exists in file:

```
int customerID (int cCheck, int count)
{
    FILE * pcustomer;
    int size = sizeof (struct customer);

    struct customer temp;

    rewind (pcustomer);
    while (fread (&temp,size,count,pcustomer)==1)
    {
        if (*temp.idnum == cCheck)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You never increment `count` it seems

Comment: count is incremented towards the end of the program, when the user is asked if he/she would like to continue entering input

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns the number of successfully matched items, I think you mean:

```
while (scanf ("%d",&checkID) == 1 && customerID(checkID, count)==1).
```

You should make sure `count` doesn't exceed `MAXCUS` only increment when you successfully read a unique ID, and you don't need an array of integer for `idnum` since each record has only one.

Also the function `customerID` is obviously wrong, here you read more than one `customer` structure and write to `temp` which is a single `customer` structure, this is most likely why it crashes:

```
 while (fread (&temp,size,count,pcustomer)==1)
```

It's much easier if you keep track of IDs in an array instead of reading from file every time you want to check if a new ID is unique.

Comment: ah yes, you are right... that test condition is wrong - the program is still crashing though. Is the logic behind the program good?

Comment: @user1816546 what is `idnum` ? show the declaration of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

idnum is an array of integers. Is that really what you want, not just a simple integer?

I'm pretty sure that if you remove `[MAX_ID]` from your struct, things will work much better.

However, I reserve the right to alter the motivation as to why it's crashing once we see the code that is after the ID check code.